# Need advice on Windows Server 2003 security for website use

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, anti-virus

I hope some really cool experts can share their knowledge with me.

We have a dedicated server to host our online store

1. Runs SQL 2005
2. No uploading by web viewers, strictly to sell goods
3. Server hosts a secure payment page for credit card processing. We don't store card data
4. Subsequently, Server needs to be PCI-compliant
5. No mail server function or FTP
6. Server not connected to any other servers or PC

Questions:

1. Do I need anti-virus, firewall or other software?
2. If yes, can anyone recommend one?
3. How do I backup server?
4. In addition, I have a programmer who has user account in the server. How do I setup security policy so that he does not take away company data in database? He tweaks DB code every now and then.

Thanks a lot for the time and for every kind soul who attempted to answer these questions. Merry Christmas

Comment: I would think SQL injection is a bigger threat than most of the stuff you have listed above. Biggest holes in web systems is unsanitized SQL queries. Make sure you look into that strongly.

Comment: thanks for the reply Tim. Yes that has been looked after. We have a great DB guy just that we don't have a good server admin yet. Even if we do later on, I'd like to cross check with experts here :)

Comment: If security is a concern why use server 2003 and not 2008R2?

Comment: Right now the scope of your question is far to large for a good answer and several aspects of it are off-topic here.

Comment: zoredache is right, this is several questions. Of which a few are off topic. 1 and 4 are topical, 3 verges on too broad. 2 is right out.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need anti-virus, firewall or other software?

Yes

> If yes, can anyone recommend one?

No. that is a shopping question.

> How do I backup server?

Seriously?  You run a backup program like ntbackup or something else you buy saveing the results to some form of remote/removeable media.  The are entire books on this subject.

> In addition, I have a programmer who has user account in the server. How do I setup security policy so that he does not take away company data in database? He tweaks DB code every now and then.

Setup a dev server for him.  Don't give him direct access to the production database.